# Consuming XYZ tile map servers on Google Earth Engine Apps

Tags: google-earth-engine, tiles

I was wondering if there's any way (or hack) to consume XYZ tile map servers directly from Google Earth Engine Apps. Specifically, I'm interested in adding Strava Cycling Heatmaps (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Strava) as a layer on one of my applications (https://danilolessa.users.earthengine.app/view/slope-pop-railway).

I did search exhaustively, and the only integrations points that I did found so far are:

- Using Python's `geemap` library (https://geemap.org/workshops/GeoPython_2021/), which is unsatisfactory, are there's no way to recompute the opacity without refreshing and reloading the map. Also, making an public web app becomes more difficult.
- Using QGIS and related plugins. Also unsatisfactory as there's code refactor involved.

Ideally, the solution should be a JS snippet that I could enter directly on the Google Earth Engine Code Editor. Any hints?

Comment: Did you have a look to voila dashboard (https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila) and ipywidget (https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ? it could allow you to build a stand alone Python based application and use geemap

Comment: @PierrickRambaud thanks for the answer! I've explored using `geemap` with `streamlit` at https://github.com/danlessa/strava-heatmap/blob/main/streamlit_app.py and I was able to create a standalone Python app, however there are several bits that are underwhelming when compared to the vanilla GEE apps as described on the first bullet point.

It's definitely preferable to not have a standalone app. But I'm not sure if this is possible